# Fetch the value of element dynamically in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm not sure if this is the question directly relate to Vue or JavaScript, but as it involves 'refs' from VueJs, i have posted question here.

I've multiple input text elements in my DOM. They are named as txtScore1, txtScore2, txtScore3 etc. On my click button event I want to fetch the value from say txtScore1. But how can I pass this refernce dynamically in this.$refs.{{ #some way of referring txtScore1 dynamically# }}.value?

I'm creating input element as follows:
`<input v-bind:ref="'txtScore' + props.item.Id" type="text"/>`

can you please help?

Thanks,
Mihir

Comment: `this.$refs['txtScore' + someVariableContainingNumber1].value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stating to props data, then the following is a wrong way:

```
<input v-bind:ref="'txtScore' + props.item.Id" type="text"/>
```

You should just use `item.Id`.

To your question,

You need to pass the item object in your input handler:

```
<input v-bind:ref="'txtScore' + item.Id" type="text" @input="handler(item)" />
```

In your method:

```
methods: { // or, whatever you need
  handler(item) {
    //use ref value like this:
    //this.$refs['txtScore' + item.id].value
  }
}
```

---

But, this is really unnecessary, you can simply use the $event object instead of using $refs:

```
<input type="text" @input="handler($event)" />
```

And then, just use the following:

```
handler(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

---

And even more, why don't you simply use `v-model`?

```
<input type="text" v-model="item" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation and the [object property accessors/bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    props: {item: {Id: 11, value: "Click me"}}
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var someVar = 11;
    console.log("11:", this.$refs['txtScore' + someVar].value);
  },
  methods: {
    goClick(Id) {
      console.log('You have clicked '+ Id + ', with value: "' + this.$refs['txtScore' + Id].value + '"');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-bind:ref="'txtScore' + props.item.Id" type="text" v-model="props.item.value" @click="goClick(props.item.Id)" />
</div>
```

Though you probably won't need it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    props: {item: {Id: 11, value: "Click me"}}
  },
  methods: {
    goClick(item, value) {
      console.log('Clicked item '+ item.Id + ', with value: "' + value + '"');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="props.item.value" @click="goClick(props.item, $event.target.value)" />
</div>
```